# Paraphrase a clause that I don't understand

Tags: phrase-request

I don't understand the "that she meant what I think she did" part:

> I really hope... that she meant what I think she did.

Can it be paraphrased to clarify this?

Here is the fuller context:

> *My heart was beating so fast. I rolled over, I felt so... I don't know, nervous? After a minute she put her arm around me, and was so close, and whispered in my ear, "I really like you." I just nodded my head and I really hope she could tell. I really hope... that she meant what I think she did.*

Comment: It would help if you told us what you want the sentence to mean. Why not keep the sentence as is?

Comment: Becouse i dont get "that she meant what I think she did" phrase.

Comment: What's the context? That sentence on its own could have different meanings depending on the context.

Comment: After a minute she put her arm around me, and was so close, and whispered in my ear, "I really like you" I just nodded my head and I really hope she could tell. I really hope... that she meant what I think she did.

Comment: I think OP is asking for a **paraphrase** that replaces and explains the meaning of the phrase in question. ... **1)** She meant X. **2)** I think she meant A. **3)** I hope that X = A.

Comment: Igor, I've included the context in the question. If you want a paraphrase, it is imperative to describe the context. "Mary had a little lamb" can mean different things in the pasture and in the restaurant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me like the narrator is falling in love. He is full of hope.

I'd paraphrase it like this:

> I like her. I like her a lot. I think she just confessed that she likes me, too. **I hope I'm not misinterpreting her remarks; I hope she really does like me.**

In the sentence, "...what I think she did" refers to "...what I think she meant." So, he is saying, "I hope she means what I think she means." In other words, "I hope I'm not making faulty assumptions about what she is saying."